# Most efficient way to map IDataReader to a C# object, also catering for deep-copy?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, data-access-layer, idatareader

we have a scenario where we use Enterprise Library Data package for the purposes of our data access needs. We have implemented a [Generic Data Reader](http://blog.2mas.xyz/generic-data-mapper-for-datareader/) to hydrate our data into business objects. However we are looking for a more efficient way to do this, that will also cater for deep copy of child collections within objects without the use of reflection since we are dealing with large volumes of data. The Generic Data Reader also doesn't perform well with large amounts of data. I know if we used EF, it could solve this but we are not at a stage in which we can replace our whole data access layer. Is there an alternative or an industry standard to achieving this?

Comment: The single most efficient way to do this is to write individual code for each reader and object.  But I suspect that's not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: it is very hard to say anything without more details and a specific scenario...

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, we have extracted this generic mapper in our reusable codebase and its used in all our data access methods. Basically, a call is made to the database using EntLib's ExecuteReader method which returns a IDataReader. We then hydrate the information from the Reader into our objects. Paddy, I understand what you mean, however, we need a generic method of doing it, so that we can reuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you hand code the mappers? It's the fastest way to do it, and you create a mapper only once during the project lifetime, right? In projects living five-ten years the amount of time it takes is negligible compared to what you get (easy to correct errors, no need to interpret OR/M errors or their "simplicity").

```
public interface IEntityMapper
{
   object Map(IDataRecord record);
}

public void UserMapper  : IEntityMapper
{
    public void Map(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var user = new User();
        user.FirstName = record["firstName"]
    }
}
```

If you got a very large number of records you need to use the `number` indexer instead to prevent name lookups:

```
public void UserMapper  : IEntityMapper
{
    public void Map(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var user = new User();

        //requires that you specify columns in your SELECT query
        //to not break the mapper in future versions.
        user.FirstName = record[0]
    }
}
```

In your repository you can do like this:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;
    private UserMapper _mapper = new UserMapper();

    public IReadOnlyList<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        using (var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, UserName FROM Users";
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var users = new List<User>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   var user = _mapper.Map(reader);
                   users.Add(user);
                }
                return users;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can even move everything to an extension method:

```
public static class CommandExtensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> ToList<T>(this IDbCommand cmd, IDataMapper mapper)
    {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var items = new List<T>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               var item= _mapper.Map(reader);
               items.Add(item);
            }
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

which gives you even more lightweight repositories:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;
    private UserMapper _mapper = new UserMapper();

    public IReadOnlyList<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        using (var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, UserName FROM Users";
            return cmd.ToList<User>(_mapper);
        }
    }
}
```

**Deep copy**

Regarding Deep copies I tried to avoid working with complex entities (unless the child entities in fact are value objects). Better to refer to other entities using ID's as it's otherwise hard to keep the responsibility for an entity in one place in your code.

When it comes to mapping I would probably introduce a convention where sub objects are mapped using an alternative method in the mapping interface:

```
public interface IEntityMapper
{
   object Map(IDataRecord record);
   object Map(IDataRecord record, string prefix);
}
```

The prefix can be used as a convention to indicate that information is fetched from multiple tables using a join.

```
public void UserMapper  : IEntityMapper
{
    private AddressMapper _childMapper = new AddressMapper();

    public void Map(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var user = new User();
        user.FirstName = record["FirstName"]
        user.Address = _childMapper.Map(record, "Address_");
    }
}
```

.. which would make your repository method look like this:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;
    private UserMapper _mapper = new UserMapper();

    public IReadOnlyList<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        using (var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Id, UserName, Address.City as Address_City 
                                FROM Users 
                                JOIN Address ON (Address.Id = Users.AddressId)";
            return cmd.ToList<User>(_mapper);
        }
    }
}
```

I've written about ADO.NET and (my) best practices: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/04/ado-net-the-right-way/

Comment: Thank you @jguffin, definately something I can work with. Since we are using this for our reusable library, and also have a custom generator tool using DSL, we can perhaps create T4 templates to generate the mapper classes alongside our data transfer objects.

Comment: 1. Why do you create the IEntityMapper interface if you don't actually use it in your code? 2. How do you integrate the mapper in the repository with writes (e.g. CreateUserInDb(User user){ .. } method) ?

Comment: if i map a field named as 'ContactName' while my query doesn't return any 'ContactName' then what will happen ? error ? how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, you can dynamically build dynamic code that is close to hard-coded efficiency.

Let's hand make a simple core of ADO:

```
// Code by Flithor(Mr. Squirrel.Downy)
// License: MIT
// == Warning ==
// Does not work in every possible situation
// Use at your own risk

/// <summary>
/// Getter <see cref="MethodInfo"/> of each common type of <see cref="IDataRecord"/>
/// </summary>
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> IDataRecordGetterMethods = typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1 && m.Name == "Get" + m.ReturnType.Name)
    .ToDictionary(m => m.ReturnType);
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="MethodInfo"/> of<see cref="IDataRecord.IsDBNull"/> of <see cref="IDataRecord"/>
/// </summary>
private static readonly MethodInfo isDbNullMethod = typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethod(nameof(IDataRecord.IsDBNull));

/// <summary>
/// Convert <see cref="IDataReader "/> to an entity sequence
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> CastTo<T>(this IDataReader reader) where T : new()
{
    Func<IDataRecord, T> instanceBuilder = null;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (instanceBuilder == null)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            // get orderd fields from first line
            var fields = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToArray();
            instanceBuilder = BuildAssginer<T>(fields);
            // build lambda just spent about 10 ms
            Console.WriteLine($"Build lambda cost：{sw.Elapsed}");
        }

        yield return instanceBuilder(reader);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Build Entity builder lambda
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fields">Orderd fields of result datas</param>
private static Func<IDataRecord, TResult> BuildAssginer<TResult>(string[] fields) where TResult : new()
{
    var createdType = typeof(TResult);

    // new Tresult()
    var ctor = Expression.New(createdType);
    var properties = typeof(TResult).GetProperties().ToDictionary(pinfo => pinfo.Name.ToLower());

    //Map indexs of fields on PropertyInfo, for efficiency
    var indexToPropMap = fields.Select((field, index) => new { field, index })
        .GroupJoin(properties, o => o.field.ToLower(), prop => prop.Key.ToLower(),
            (o, props) => new { o.index, prop = props.FirstOrDefault().Value })
        .Where(o => o.prop != null)
        .OrderBy(o => o.index)
        .ToDictionary(o => o.index, o => o.prop);
    //define lambda input parameter of IDataRecord type
    var recordParamExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDataRecord));
    //get property 
    var propAssginExps = indexToPropMap.Select(kv =>
    {
        // get field type and the underlying type of nullable type(maybe)
        var propType = kv.Value.PropertyType;
        var underType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType);
        // build get value expression for most most appropriate case
        var getValuesExp = underType != null
            ? Expression.Convert(
                Expression.Call(recordParamExp, IDataRecordGetterMethods[underType],
                    Expression.Constant(kv.Key)), propType)
            : (Expression)Expression.Call(recordParamExp, IDataRecordGetterMethods[propType],
                Expression.Constant(kv.Key));
        // is not value type or is nullable
        var propCanNull = !propType.IsValueType || underType != null;
        var getFieldValueExp = propCanNull
            // may null field check is dbnull or not
            ? Expression.Condition(
                Expression.Call(recordParamExp, isDbNullMethod, Expression.Constant(kv.Key)),
                Expression.Default(propType),
                getValuesExp)
            // return not nullable value directly
            : getValuesExp;
        // set field
        return Expression.Bind(kv.Value, getFieldValueExp);
    });
    // entity initializer
    // sample:
    // new TResult
    // {
    //     No = record.GetInt32(0),
    //     Name = record.GetString(1),
    //     Num = record.IsNull(2) ? default(Int64) : record.GetInt64(2)
    // }
    var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(ctor, propAssginExps);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<IDataRecord, TResult>>(memberInit, recordParamExp).Compile();
}
```

Knowing how to use `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, you can write deep copy by yourself.